Time on OpenWeather
I was making a system where it automatically saves the temp and the time when the temp was at. The thing is, since im new, I don't know how to get the time, ive been struggling alot. Thank you!
I don't actually havent done anything since im confused.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
